# Flutter: How to search on list<class>?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asp.net-web-api

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create search list, it doesn't update on the UI widget, this is my code. im using bloc

```
void Updatemodel (String value) {
    setState(() {
      
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
    
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {   
      displaymodel = 
      data.where((element) => element.rows!.any((elements) => elements.id!.toString().
      toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
      ).toList();
    });
      
    });
  }
```

i want to search id which is class in class, how to solve this? the variable displaymodel,data is in List<(Model) >.

this is my model.

```
class listmodel {
  String? drainageid;
  int? datacount;
  int? resultcount;
  String? page;
  List<Rows>? rows;
  String? error;

  listmodel(
      {this.drainageid,
      this.datacount,
      this.resultcount,
      this.page,
      this.rows});

  listmodel.withError(String errorMessage) {
    error = errorMessage;
  }

  listmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    drainageid = json['drainageid'];
    datacount = json['datacount'];
    resultcount = json['resultcount'];
    page = json['page'];
    if (json['rows'] != null) { rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
  }

  factory listmodel.fromJsonn(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    var _rows;
    if (json['rows'] != null) { _rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
    return listmodel(
    drainageid : json['drainageid'],
    datacount : json['datacount'],
    resultcount : json['resultcount'],
    page : json['page'],
    rows: _rows);
  }
    
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['drainageid'] = drainageid;
    data['datacount'] = datacount;
    data['resultcount'] = resultcount;
    data['page'] = page;
    if (rows != null) {
      data['rows'] = rows!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Rows {
  String? id;
  DateTime? dateoflastinsp;
  DateTime? dateofinsp;
  String? inspby;

  Rows({this.id, this.dateoflastinsp, this.dateofinsp, this.inspby});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    dateoflastinsp = json['dateoflastinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateoflastinsp'] as String);
    dateofinsp = json['dateofinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateofinsp'] as String);
    inspby = json['inspby'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['dateoflastinsp'] = dateoflastinsp;
    data['dateofinsp'] = dateofinsp;
    data['inspby'] = inspby;
    return data;
  }
}
```

the problem the search query doesnt filter the listview, number of list after query remain the same

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? What do your classes look like? Why are there not one, but two `!` in your statement? Are you 100% certain they are not null? If you are, why doesn*t your class reflect that by making that member not-null?

Comment: @nvoigt im new to flutter, so i try and error every method i can find, so i cant answer anything you asked